# The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists -- without using any IDE

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I have seen all the previously asked questions but all the questions were asked while servlet was trying to run using some IDE but in my case I am just testing my helloWorld servlet program using tomcat 7 .

my points are given below:

1) server : http://localhost:8080/ -->doing fine

2) http://localhost:8080/test throwing the above error

directory structure used by me:

webapps->myFolder->WEB-INF->classes

my web.xml file

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>abcd</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>Shashi</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>abcd</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your web app exists in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat XX\webapps as somehow Tomcat folder exists both here and in C:\tomcat-XXXX for my case. After moving my application inside there it works. It seems the real directory it is pointing is that one.